# how to trim the records before 3rd occurrence in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a query to get the string after 3rd occurance of '~' in postgresql:

```
input:
1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8
7~8~22~99~1

Output:
4~5~6~7~8
99~1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like "a-horse-with-no-name"'s answer.  But here is another method using regular expressions:

```
select regexp_replace(str, '^([^~]*[~]){3}$', '')
from (values ('1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8'), ('7~8~22~99~1')) v(str);
```

Or `regexp_matches()`:

```
select str, (regexp_matches(str, '^([^~]*[~]){3}(.*)$'))[2] as retval
from (values ('1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8'), ('7~8~22~99~1'), ('1~2')) v(str)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bf89549877d608c829a7823914ac7c17) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Postgres doesn't have an "find the nth occurance" function. But given the format of your string, I think arrays can be used for this:

```
with test_data (input) as (
  values 
     ('1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8'),
     ('7~8~22~99~1')
)     
select input, array_to_string((string_to_array(input, '~'))[4:], '~') new_value
from test_data;
```

returns:

```
input           | new_value
----------------+----------
1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8 | 4~5~6~7~8
7~8~22~99~1     | 99~1
```

Comment: getting error on the above query ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "]", can you please help resolve it, string_to_array is working fine

Comment: @pradeeppanda . . . Here is a db fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7fa05be561712f74bb6ad95c9336d9b2.

Comment: still getting same error without [:4] it's working fine but whole string is returned. May be my postgresql version is older.

Comment: @pradeeppanda: which Postgres version are you using? `select version();` will tell you